# Explanation to Average DC Estimator implemented in C

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I´m using MAX30102 sensor to calculate Heart rate. This sensor emitter a light and measure how much was absorbed by arterial blood + skin + muscle and other things (dummy explanation).
So, big part of data is continuous values and a little part is arterial pulsation blood (that I can use to count pulses).
The first item of signal process is remove DC component.
I try it using a filter with float variable and now I found implementation that no use it (I will put this code in microcontroller and I want the best performance).
I tested new function and It worked very well, but I cannot understand It. So I´m here to ask help to understand the mathematical used in this function.

The Figure below can help to explain:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRmI2.jpg

```c
//  Average DC Estimator
static int16_t averageDCEstimator(int32_t *p, uint16_t x)
{
    *p += ((((long) x << 15) - *p) >> 4);
    return (*p >> 15);
}
```

*p is mean calculated in the past, so new  mean uses past mean plus actual measured sample.
x is actual measured sample (the data send by sensor have 18 bits).

Comment: Curious, what is the max value of `uint16_t x`?  I suspect a problem with overflow.

Comment: @chux, I suspect that's supposed to be handled by the `(long) x` bit.

Comment: @paxdiablo It is that `x` may be [too great](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57404571/2410359).,

Comment: In MAX30102 you can setup current applied too leds, with more current, more output you can have. **uint16_t x** stay working because I´m applying less than 50% of current in it.
I will try change *** *p *** to *uint64_t* and x to **uint16_t**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like an approximate running average value.  It's similar to a windowed average, except that each new value added influences the mean by a percentage.  So it is always biased toward the newest value.  As a bonus, it requires no buffering of previous values.  Let's break it down.

First, let's talk units.  `x << 15` shifts `x` left by 15 bits, effectively multiplying it by 32768.  Note also the final average shifts the value stored at `p` to the right by 15 bits.

This indicates that the value stored at `p` is using a trick known as "fixed-point" math, where you use extra bits of an integer as if they are decimal places.

So, the value at `p` is the current running average in fixed-point.  When `x` arrives, it's converted into fixed-point and you then you calculate its deviation from the current running average.

You then take that delta and shift it right by 4 bits, effectively dividing by 16.  That value is added to the running average.  This means that each new value can affect the mean by roughly one sixteenth.  In other words, a single new value has a 6.25% influence on the current mean.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this averager is faulty when `uint16_t x` regularly exceeds about 32767

This output of this low pass filter will eventually approach `x`.  When `x` is above the `int16_t` range, eventually the conversion of `*p >> 15` leads to *undefined behavior*.

Recommend to insure `x <= 32767`

Answer (score 0):

p points 32bits data's address. When you return p>>15 this will be 32bit value but your code returns 16bit unsigned. First I recommed you to use uint32_t if your mean will not be minus anymore. Also you mentioned that your sensor data is 18bits but your x value is uint16_t. You miss your 2bits data (MSB and MSB-1) from sensor. I recommend you to use all value in uin32_t. If you want to return 16 bit value you can use type casting. 
For example;

return (uint16_t)(your value);
At that point you have to be sure your data should not be higher than 2^16;